# Check existence of column values depending on id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following scenario for which I try to build a **SQL-Query**:

For 3 different "**level**"-column types (category, file, folder), for each of them given a corresponding "level_id", I try to get the existence (if a value is set or not) of the columns "**require_login**" and "**access_key**".

- **Addition:**
  In case of the "**folder**"-level the column "dirname" is used the express the id instead of the column "level_id"

---

**The table:**

[image: the data table]

---

**Example:**

Input data set:

- level = **category** : level_id = 3
- level = **file** : level_id = 5
- level = **folder** : dirname = "none/occuring/folder"

This should give me a descriptor for each of the levels, expressing if 'require_login' and 'access_key' are set or not. E.g. 00 if nothing is set and 01 if only 'access_key' is set.

---

**Background:**

What I intend to do is building a descriptor for the properties of each level which should be used in a different table.

So far I've queried all the entries with matching level and level_id and then processed it in PHP to get the descriptor.

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (level='file' AND level_id = 5) 
   OR (level='category' AND level_id = 3) 
   OR (level='folder' AND dirname = 'none/occuring/folder')
```

It's probably not very efficient and therefore it would be nice to perform the whole operation in a SQL-Query.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: So far I've queried all the entries with matching level and level_id and then processed it in PHP to get the descriptor. Like this: `SELECT * from table WHERE 
(level='file' AND level_id = 5) OR
(level='category' AND level_id = 3) OR
(level='folder' AND dirname = 'none/occuring/folder')` It's probably not very efficient and therefore it would be nice to perform the whole operation in a SQL-Query.

Comment: Can you post expected results for the 4 lines in you screenshot.